# How can I get current page title in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using twenty twelve theme in WordPress.Can someone tell me ,
how can I get the current page title function?.

I tried this function but it gives me the Post title not the page title .
Thank You.

```
    <?php echo get_the_title();?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wp_title()`

Fore more information:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-page-title-not-the-post-title

Comment: Thanks , it does something , it outputs like this **» BlogAuthor** , i want only Blog since thats the curent page .

Comment: `wp_title('');` use this to get rid of the >>

Comment: this is ok but it outputs BlogAuthor , ill keep digging to see if i can get only the name of the page .Ty